# Insert data into remote MongoDB using meteor.js

Tags: meteor

I am inserting data into local MongoDB using

test.insert({"name" : "abc"});

So is there any way to insert data into remote MongoDB 
using the same code i.e. without much changing the code
to insert and retrieve from remote MongoDB.

Thanks & Regards,

Comment: Do you want to use a remote mongo instance to store the data from your meteor app? Or are you trying to make an app that accesses two different instances of mongodb, one local and one remote?

Comment: I want to insert data into remote MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

deploy using this:

$ PORT=3000 MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp node bundle/main.js

http://docs.meteor.com/#deploying , section : Running on your own infrastructure